# How to Add/Subtract columns based on a particular value in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column called Total_Order_Amount in Dataframe whose value will be based on the Orderstatus. ex if order status is shipped then Total_Order_Amount = item_price + Tax - item_Discount - Tax_Discount. If the order status is cancelled then Total_Order_Aount = item_price - item_Discount.

Input DataFrame

```
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+
| Order id | Order Status | item price | Tax  | item discount | tax discount |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+
| 1        | Shipped      | 400        | 72   | 30            | 72           |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+
| 2        | cancelled    | 200        | 36   | 5             | 0            |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+
| 3        | Shipped      | 180        | 32.4 | 18            | 0            |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+
| 4        | cancelled    | 600        | 108  | 50            | 108          |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+
| 5        | shipped      | 500        | 90   | 25            | 90           |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+
| 6        | cancelled    | 280        | 50.4 | 15            | 50.4         |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+
```

Final Output required.

```
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| Order id | Order Status | item price | Tax  | item discount | tax discount | total order amount |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 1        | Shipped      | 400        | 72   | 30            | 72           | 370                |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 2        | cancelled    | 200        | 36   | 5             | 0            | 195                |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 3        | Shipped      | 180        | 32.4 | 18            | 0            | 194.4              |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 4        | cancelled    | 600        | 108  | 50            | 108          | 550                |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 5        | shipped      | 500        | 90   | 25            | 90           | 475                |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 6        | cancelled    | 280        | 50.4 | 15            | 50.4         | 265                |
+----------+--------------+------------+------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def new_col(x):
    if x['Order Status'] == 'Shipped':
       return x['item price'] + x.Tax - x['item discount'] - x['tax discount']
    else:
       return x['item price'] - x['item discount']

df['Total_Order_Amount'] = df.apply(new_col, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(a):
    if a['Shipped'] == 'shipped':
        return a['item_price'] + a['Tax'] - a['item_Discount'] - a['Tax_Discount']
    elif a['Shipped'] == 'cancelled':
        return a['item_price'] - a['item_Discount']
    else:
        return null
    
df['Total_Order_Amount'] = pd.Series(dtype='float64')
transformedDf = df['Total_Order_Amount'].apply(lambda x: func(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without defining a function:

```
df['Total_Order_Amount'] = (
      df['item_price'] 
    + df['Tax'] 
    - df['item_Discount'] 
    - df['Tax_Discount']
)
mask_shipped = df['Shipped'] != 'shipped'
df.loc[mask_shipped, 'Total_Order_Amount'] = (
      df.loc[mask_shipped, 'item_price'] 
    - df.loc[mask_shipped, 'item_Discount']
)
```